# java en netbeans 11

Tags: java, netbeans-11

Antes para la creación de un proyecto java con netbeans había la opción  "java"

[image: Opciones Anteriores con Netbeans]

Ahora en Netbeans 11 esta opción ha desaparecido, cuál será el equivalente?

[image: Opciones actuales con Netbeans 11]

Comment: estas seguro de haber instalado java?

Comment: Creo que estan bajo el árbol de java con ant

Comment: Si, Java con Ant. Es el constructor de dependencias que quieres usar. Ant es el que usaba netbeans por defecto.